How do I make the correct path so that my favicon shows up in google chrome and live server?
I’m having a problem with my fav icon it shows up in live server but not google chrome
I tried to Change my path but that’s not working either. I have also asked a couple other people but we can’t seem to figure it out it’s just not working
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
      <title>Wikipedia</title> 
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon " href="Img/favicon1.ico"> 
    </head> 
<body> 
    <h1>Hello world</h1> 
</body> 
</html>


Please provide your current code.

@Chrissy You need to add the code in the question itself, you that it will easier for others to help you.

There is an extra space after type definition x-icon. Also better to use favicon instead of favicon1 because some browsers look for that name by default.

Do you really have a file named favicon1.ico on folder named Img in the project directory? Do give a check.

Does the Chrome developer console (F12) show any errors? Reload the page to see all network calls.
